# Should I calibrate my Dell Latitude 5175 2-in-1's batteries?

Tags: battery

I own a Dell Latitude 5175, recently I bought a brand new keyboard which has a built-in battery...

Under Linux, My 5175's battery's health is 93% (it was 98% like a month ago), and the keyboard's battery's health is at 97%.

1. Why did the main battery's health go from 98% to 93% over a month? Is it natural?
2. Should I do a calibration?
3. Should I worry about changing the battery that has 93% health?
4. At what health percentage should I worry about changing the batteries?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do a battery Reset once or twice a year on my Lenovo laptops and that performs the calibration function.

My X1 laptop with 16 month old battery shows 51 WH capacity vs 56 WH new.

My older X230 (4 year old battery) shows 40 WH capacity vs 62 WH capacity new.

There is no issue with what you see and that is pretty normal.

1. Batteries last 3 or 4 years and need replacing as they increasingly do not hold a charge.
2. If you leave the laptop plugged in, keep the charge level about 80% to provide better overall life.  I have a charging threshold setting for this